# Setting backgroundColor of panel works outside of JTabbedPane but not inside

Tags: java, swing, background, jtabbedpane

I am having issues where the background color of my inner panel is not being set (or not being shown) when inside my JTabbedPane

I have the following structure:

```
JPanel BorderLayout:
   JTabbedPane (BorderLayout.Center):
      JPanel Default
      ..
```

When I add the inner JPanel to the borderLayout at BorderLayout.CENTER instead of the JTabbedPane then I can see the background color, however if my inner panel is in the tabbed pane and tabbed pane is added to the center then the background color is default and seems to be overriding it.

```
panel1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
tabbedPane.add(panel1);

//add tabbed pane to panel with borderlayout
//Background color of this panel is also set previously
add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about making desired components **transparent**?

```
package javaapplication31;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Color;

import java.awt.Dimension;


public class JavaApplication31
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Runnable r = new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                //let's make all TabbedPanes transparent by default
                UIManager.put("TabbedPane.contentOpaque", false);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();

                JPanel parentPanel = new JPanel();
                parentPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                frame.add(parentPanel);

                JTabbedPane tp = new JTabbedPane();               
                parentPanel.add(tp);

                //Make transparent panel
                JPanel panelTransparent = new JPanel();
                panelTransparent.setOpaque(false); // this makes panel transparent
                panelTransparent.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
                tp.addTab("Transparent", panelTransparent);

                //Make panel (by default panel is opaque)
                JPanel panelOpaque = new JPanel();
                tp.addTab("Opaque", panelOpaque);

                frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```